# Find function that satisfies some criteria

Tags: limits, functions

Let say $ a $ a is some constant.
I need to find function $f(x)$ that meets this criteria:
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty }(f(x)) = a $$
$$ \lim_{x\to -\infty }(f(x)) = -a $$
$$ f(0) = 0 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions

$$x\mapsto \frac {2a}\pi \arctan x$$

$$x\mapsto \begin{cases} \frac x{1+x} & \text{for } x\ge 0 \\ \frac x{1-x} & \text{for } x\le 0\end{cases}$$

seem to fit your criteria.

Comment: Thanks man.. The first one was the one I needed

Comment: @MaxAdamyan The other one has additional property: its value is rational iff its argument is rational. However, it's not that smooth as the first one.

Comment: This is a very good function. Not just continuous, in fact infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

If continuity is not required:

$f(x)=a$ for $x>0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=-a$ for $x<0$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example:
\begin{align*}
x\mapsto\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
\end{align*}